# Width of dynamic rectangle in spark ar is not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I've created a dynamic rectangle with a `width` and `height` of `100`, and then changed its `x position` to `10`. Spark AR shows its position as `10`, but not the width/height, which appear as `0,03748`

[Here's a screenshot of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YYFt.jpg)

```
const [dynamicRectangle] = await Promise.all([
        Scene.create("PlanarImage", {
            "name": "Rectangle",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100,
            "hidden": false,
            "material": material,
        }),
    ]);

const dynamicRectangleTransform = dynamicRectangle.transform;
dynamicRectangleTransform.x = 10;
```

Why? I figured it might have something to do with the `canvas width`, because multiplying it by the `rectangle width`, returns the correct number, HOWEVER it seems to have broken the code somehow, because when I add these lines of code, [this happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4DDK.jpg)

```
const newWidth = dynamicRectangle.width.mul(canvas.bounds.width);
dynamicRectangle.width = newWidth;

const newHeight = dynamicRectangle.height.mul(canvas.bounds.height);
dynamicRectangle.height = newHeight;
```

In case you didn't notice from the screenshot, it now properly appears as `100`, but now the rectangle doesn't appear in the canvas even though it should be visible, and `position` is back to `0`, when it should clearly be `10`. It isn't visible in my example, but it also makes so every line of `Diagnostics.watch()` stop working.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried hundreds of things and this keeps happening.

Comment: How are you adding the child to the scene? AFAIK a rectangle needs to be added as a child of a canvas

Comment: I think this is a bug tbh. If I change the width/height afterwards instantiation, then I see the correct values in the properties inspector, but the rendering in the viewport is still broken and tiny as f*ck. (If I add the rectangle directly as a child of the 'Focal Distance' rather than the canvas, then it appears in the middle but size is again broken and rendered in a different scale)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Convert your rectangle to a Block
2. Using script, pass the new width and height to the block.

   Ex : block.inputs.setScalar("widthValue", 123);
3. Within the Block, receive the value and update the rectangle using patches.